# How to display all installed fonts in a ComboBox

Tags: c#, fonts, combobox, winui-3

I need to display all the user's installed fonts in a WinUI 3 `ComboBox`. I'm using this code:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="FontComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static Fonts.SystemFontFamilies}}">
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source}" FontFamily="{Binding Source}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

But this causes the error:

> The type 'x:Static' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.

Not sure what an assembly reference is.

What would I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, WinUI 3 doesn't support [x:Static](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2232).

So, let me show you another way to achieve this using the [Win2D](https://github.com/microsoft/Win2D) NuGet package.

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="FontFamiliesExample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:local="using:FontFamiliesExample"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:win2d="using:Microsoft.Graphics.Canvas.Text"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <StackPanel>
        <ComboBox ItemsSource="{x:Bind win2d:CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies()}" />
    </StackPanel>

</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

WinUI 3 doesn't support `x:Static`. And WinUI 3 also doesn't support `Fonts.SystemFontFamilies`.

If you want to display all installed fonts. I suggest you could try to install the `Win2D` Nuget package.

[image: Screenshot of application to install]

And then you could use [CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies Method](https://microsoft.github.io/Win2D/WinUI2/html/M_Microsoft_Graphics_Canvas_Text_CanvasTextFormat_GetSystemFontFamilies.htm) to get a list of font families available.
Here is the code:

```
  public List<string> Fonts
    {
        get
        {
            return CanvasTextFormat.GetSystemFontFamilies().OrderBy(f => f).ToList();
        }
    }




<ComboBox x:Name="FontsCombo"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Fonts}">

    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: Your answer is pretty much a direct copy of Andrew Keep Coding's answer.